# ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecutedAsync save logger object to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-6.1

I am using a global ActionFilterAttribute to plug in my logger logic and I want to save the logger object into the database.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class RequireHttpHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public override async Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext httpActionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpActionExecutedContext executedContext;
        var WebServiceRequestURI = httpActionExecutedContext.Request.RequestUri;
        var WebServiceRequestMethod = httpActionExecutedContext.Request.Method;
        Task<string> content = httpActionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string WebServiceRequestBody = content.Result;
        if (WebServiceRequestBody == "")
            WebServiceRequestBody = "No-Content";
        var UserID = httpActionExecutedContext.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims.First().Value;
        // Get the sender address
        var myRequest = ((HttpContextWrapper)httpActionExecutedContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request;
        var IPAddress = myRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress))
        {
            string[] ipRange = IPAddress.Split(',');
            int le = ipRange.Length - 1;
            string trueIP = ipRange[le];
        }
        else
        {
            IPAddress = myRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        }

        var webserviceRequestDate = DateTime.Now;
        FMBP_ActionLog fMBP_ActionLog = new FMBP_ActionLog();
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestString = WebServiceRequestURI.ToString();
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestMethod = WebServiceRequestMethod.ToString();
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestBody = WebServiceRequestBody;
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestDate = DateTime.Now;
        fMBP_ActionLog.IPAddress = IPAddress;
        fMBP_ActionLog.UserID = UserID;
        fMBP_ActionLog.StatusCode = (int)httpActionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode;
        db.FMBP_ActionLog.Add(fMBP_ActionLog);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Whats the best way to save FMBP_ActionLog to database? I have been getting a number of random errors like this

```
"ExceptionMessage":"The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state.
```

Comment: I don't actually see where `db` comes from? Can you include the code where you are initializing your DbContext please?

Comment: @timothyclifford  - added the whole class

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem. It was not disposing the db context.

```
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        FMBP_ActionLog fMBP_ActionLog = new FMBP_ActionLog();
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestString = WebServiceRequestURI.ToString();
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestMethod = WebServiceRequestMethod.ToString();
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestBody = WebServiceRequestBody;
        fMBP_ActionLog.WebServiceRequestDate = DateTime.Now;
        fMBP_ActionLog.IPAddress = IPAddress;
        fMBP_ActionLog.UserID = UserID;
        fMBP_ActionLog.StatusCode = (int)httpActionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode;
        db.FMBP_ActionLog.Add(fMBP_ActionLog);
        // Perform data access using the context 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```